# Why does yield + iter() not produce output?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def myf2():
    for x in "abzdef":
        yield x


#print(list(myf2()))

print(list(iter(myf2,'z')))
```

I expected ['a', 'b'] but in https://repl.it/languages/python3 I get a wait before the cursor comes back with no output.
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 1):

You can see the problem if you attempt to iterate the return of `iter`:

```
for x in iter(myf2, 'z'):
    print(x)
```

This will print out infinite generator objects, not letters. This was the problem. `list` would take an infinite amount of time to evaluate an infinite list (or, at least as much time as it takes to crash with a memory error).

Why does this happen? Because calling `myf2`, which `iter` does, returns a *generator*. When you iterate the returned generator, you'll get the letters.

If you wanted to do what you're trying to do, you could use itertool's `takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def myf2():
    for x in "abzdef":
        yield x


gen = myf2()
print(list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'z', gen)))

# ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this gives a memory error.

`list(generator)` calls the `next` method until a `StopIteration` Error is raised.

The `next` method of `iter(myf2, 'z')` returns a generator created by `myf2` each times it is call. It will never reach 'z', and never ends.

You can check this with `print(type(iter(myf2, 'z')))`

You will receive a `MemoryError`